# How to load Google Maps V3 with JQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to load Google Maps V3 with JQUERY AJAX? Below is my partial code. I retrieve some tweets from twitter API  based on user search term and I want to load users' locations on Google Maps. This partial code is written inside index.php and I use form to get the value of textfield. But when I try to load it, the map doesn't appear. So I try to copy all the html code using view source and put them inside another html file and load it again. The map appears. The problem is map doesn't work when form is used and how I can load it using JQUERY AJAX. I put showMap() function inside button onclick event and I use form to retrieve textfield value.

Can anyone give me some ideas or useful links for my problem so that I can make reference?

Thanks in advance...

```
    function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.56952058,-1.16262487);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 2,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), 
            myOptions);

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tweetList); $i++)
{

echo "var point$i = new google.maps.LatLng(". $tweetList[$i]->getLat(). ",". $tweetList[$i]->getLng().");\n";

echo "var marker$i = new google.maps.Marker({position: point$i, 
          map: map});\n";

}
```

?>

```
function showMap() {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't just put the link in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: This is just a partial code. In my real code, I put <script> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the twitter api, but your code should resemble the code below to get your twitter feed on the browser side using jQuery and ajax.

```
function init() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.56952058,-1.16262487);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), myOptions);
    getTweets();
}

function getTweets() {
    $.post('http://www.Twitter.com/endpoint',{term:'tweet search'}, function(data) {
        // assuming that twitter returns a JSON feed
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        // I don't know the twitter api, but here is the general idea:
        for (var i = 0; i<data.tweets.length; i++) {
            var tweet = data.tweets[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({options:'here'});
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```